# C++ ConcurrencyInAction: 7.2.2 Stopping those pesky leaks: managing memory in lock-free data structures

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, stack, atomic

I am trying to understand how more than one thread hold head pointer in pop(), If two threads hold head pointer at "node *old_head = head.load();" then the first thread will complete the loop by updating the head and at the end let's say we delete the old_head and Thread1 completes it's work, now Thread2 is still holding deleted old_head and it will enter the while loop and old_head and current head are not same, so it will go to else if condition and set "old_head = head;" and loop again and update the head and come out of loop and delete the old_head.

In the above process Thread2 never dereference the deleted node because it will come to else if condition if head and old_head are not same.

But as per the Author from C++ ConcurrencyInAction Book do we really need to check for other Threads holding the old_head ?

> From C++ ConcurrencyInAction Book:
> The basic problem is that you want to free a node, but you can’t do so until you’re sure there are no other threads that still hold pointers to it.

```
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class lock_free_stack
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        std::shared_ptr<T> data;
        node *next;
        node(T const &data_) : data(std::make_shared<T>(data_))
        {
        }
    };
    std::atomic<node *> head;

public:
    void push(T const &data)
    {
        node *const new_node = new node(data);
        new_node->next = head.load();
        while (!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node));
    } 
    std::shared_ptr<T> pop()
    {
        node *old_head = head.load();
        while (old_head && !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, old_head->next)); 
        // background steps of compare_exchange_weak
        /*      if ((old_head != nullptr) && (head == old_head))
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        head = old_head->next;
                        return true; // loop ends
                    }
                    catch(exception &e)
                    {
                        return false; // loop forever, at the end if we are deleting old_head then we are deleting head, it makes Stack without head
                    }
                }
                else if ((old_head != nullptr) && (head != old_head))
                {
                    old_head = head;
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false; // loop forever
                } */          
        return old_head ? old_head->data : std::shared_ptr<T>();
    } 
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the above process Thread2 never dereference the deleted node
> because it will come to else if condition if head and old_head are not
> same.

This is not true. Consider this line:

`head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, old_head->next)`

This will access the value of `old_head->next` before the `compare_exchange_weak` even runs. Which means if `old_head` is a dangling pointer you get **Undefined Behavoir**.

(Note that `head` will not equal `old_head` in this case and so the value of `old_head->next` will *not be used* but just accessing it before we know we'll not use it already causes the issue).

Additionally in your pseudocode for `cew` it seems you think that accessing `old_head->next` will throw an exception? This isn't true in `c++`. Accesssing a bad pointer will immediately cause **Undefined Behavoir** which means all bets are off.